# How to avoid df.apply running twice top row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am aware that the method `apply` run twice the top row to see if it can optimize my code.

Is there a way to use `apply` without running twice on the first row?

Here is my code:

```
df[["A", "B"]] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(create_store(x["C"], x["D"]),axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `tuple` of those 2 columns to the function such as

```
def create_store(tuple):
    ...
    tuple[0] #instead of x["C"]
    tuple[1] #instead of X["D"]
```